# Mondrian - Fact Table Data as XML

Tags: mysql, xml, olap, business-intelligence, mondrian

I am evaluating a Mondrian-Saiku solution for a client.

After analyzing their current database schemas, I realize that what constitutes as their 'fact table data' is currently being stored in XML's. The XML 's themselves are stored as blob datatypes in a MySQL table. Think of it like this: the table holds all the transactions of the company; the details of each transaction are stored in their own XML; each XML string is stored as one of the field values in a given transaction row.

This presents a slight dilemma since the Mondrian XML schema requires the explicit use of column names.

Short of having to extract and transfer the XML data to new tables (not realistic for my purposes due to the size of data and dependencies from other systems), is there any way I can work my client's existing setup for the purposes of a Mondrian-Saiku implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose the data in a traditional table way. What is the database here? Can you create a database view which does some xml processing on the XML in the blob and exposes the columns?

Alternatively maybe something like composite or jboss teiid can help here. These tools allow you to expose as a standard looking table, virtually anything. It may not be quick enough though!

Comment: Thanks for your input. Since posting this question, I've come to find through experimentation that the Mondrian XML supports ExtractValue() via MySQL. In this way, no changes need to be made to the existing database. The bottleneck appears to be from ExtractValue(), which is executed many, many times for data aggregation.

Comment: Ok. Ah I see; I thought you were saying the whole record was encoded in XML! So I misunderstood your question.  Yes I think Mondrian supports any SQL functions in that way. Obviously it should cache up nicely after the first execution, but if it's still too slow then you'll either need to find a faster way to parse the xml, or as suggested extract the data to a proper column anyway.  Or perhaps use Agg tables, but that is a but OTT in this case!